# gcc -fprofile-generate=path VS -fprofile-dir=path

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I was checking the `gcc` optimization args at

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

and I don't understand, if these to do the same, or not?

```
-fprofile-generate=path

    If path is specified, GCC looks at the path to
    find the profile feedback data files. See -fprofile-dir. 

-fprofile-dir=path

    Set the directory to search for the profile data files in to path.
    This option affects only the profile data generated by
    -fprofile-generate, -ftest-coverage, -fprofile-arcs and used by
    -fprofile-use and -fbranch-probabilities and its related options.
    Both absolute and relative paths can be used. By default, GCC uses
    the current directory as path, thus the profile data file appears
    in the same directory as the object file. In order to prevent
    the file name clashing, if the object file name is not an absolute path,
    we mangle the absolute path of the sourcename.gcda file and use it as
    the file name of a .gcda file. See details about the file naming in
    -fprofile-arcs. See similar option -fprofile-note.
```

To me it seems the 2 `path`-s are setting the same thing (the location where the .gcda files are written). Are they, or do I misunderstand something?